# Flutter: Why Getx not Working with deep links?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

My Entire app depends on Getx Package, because I'm using MVC structer in my app, and Getx let me easy handle (controllers, middlewars, View, routes, theme, language, ...),
But when I tried to add Deeplinking in my app I counld not handle it, Every time I tried to open link it's open  '/start' route instead of '/note/:id' route, and I got this Error in mobile screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6moNc.jpg)

is there any solution?

Comment: Can you please share you code here.

Comment: this is my route code, I added print to see if the app if passing through this or not but, I got nothing in terminal:  
GetPage(
    name: '/p/:id',
    page: () {
print("======== in Post id route");
      return const SinglePostScreenWidget();
    },
    middlewares: [AuthMiddleware()],
  ),

for the screen is just a simple screen with Text("Hello")


My entire app depends on Getx I can't switch it